# How get "rect" values using webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to get values from "rect" element using c# and selenium , I can get the "rect" element but cant view and use its values

I need to get " data-count" value and "data-date" value

this is how im getting the  rect element:

```
var calendarElements = driver.FindElement(By.Id("contributions-calendar"))
            .FindElement(By.ClassName("js-calendar-graph"))
            .FindElements(By.TagName("g"));
        foreach (var element in calendarElements)
        {
            var a = element.FindElements(By.TagName("rect"));

        }
```

and this is my html path :

[image]

I need to calculate the "data- count" value , but I just cant get it

Answer (score 0):

`data-count` is an attribute. Use `GetAttribute()` method to get the attribute value:

```
var dataCount = element.FindElement(By.TagName("rect")).GetAttribute("data-count");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a slight code change as well to what @alecxe has already suggested :

```
// loop for calendar element
foreach (var calElement in calendarElements) {
  var a = calElement.FindElements(By.TagName("rect")); 
  // another loop for the list of rect element 
  foreach (var rectElement in a) {
    var dataCount = rectElement.GetAttribute("data-count");
    var dataDate = rectElement.GetAttribute("data-date");
    //use these two accordingly
  }
}
```